# Is there a way to make the announcers talk less?

Tags: madden-12

One thing that is driving my crazy about Madden 12 is the repetition in the announcers' dialog.  It seems that there's only one scripted conversation per team to introduce the offense and defense.  I am sick of hearing how Troy Polamalu is destined for the hall of fame and Hines Ward leads the Steelers' offense.

I don't want to mute the announcers completely, just lower their verbosity - or at least these repetitive scripted introductions.  Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't played madden, but I know for the NHL games of the same genre there is a setting for "commentary or commentary frequency". Turning that down made less colour commentary occur during the games. It might be the same for Madden.

Comment: Does John Madden still do the color commentary for Madden NFL?  You could probably fix it in Madden 13 by...

Comment: @Nick, no, Cris Collinsworth replaced him starting with Madden 10.

Comment: I don't see an option to change it, and can't say from personal experience because I already turned off the volume. I'm looking around for verification from somewhere.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I've looked around and can't find anything.  It's still driving me crazy, and I'm very close to just turning off the sound altogether.  The announcing this year is so terrible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option to turn on offensive/defensive coordinator speech and subtitles. If you turn on coordinator speech, then the announcers will only speak in a handful of situations (the beginning of the game is the only one that comes to mind).

**EDIT:** These instructions are from the Xbox 360 version:

From the main menu, go to the "My Madden" -> "My Settings" -> "Game Options" -> "Coordinator Audio" (#10). It can be turned on, turned on for the headset only, or turned off. It replaces most commentary with a tutorial-ish description of what to do on the play. They're certainly less annoying than the announcers. The announcers will chime in at the beginning of the game and a handful of other times for which I haven't identified a pattern yet.

I don't know any other way to get them to talk less other than muting the announcer channel: Main menu -> "My Madden" -> "My Settings" -> "Volume Control" -> "In-Game Commentary". But you explicitly didn't want to do that; I'm only including it for completeness.

Comment: Can you please post where exactly you have to dig around? The OP stated that he's already searched a lot and couldn't find anything, so more explicit instructions would be helpful. :)

Comment: @Fallen: There you are. I just didn't want to look it up at two in the morning. ;-)

Comment: This seems to be the best thing possible.  It's not ideal, but maybe the next version of Madden will include it.  Thanks for the input!